# regex to find valide URL with or without www, including dot but excluding double dots

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to find a regex that matches URLs that include or not 'www', is followed by valide strings that can indlude dots, but not two or more consecutive dots. For sake of simplicity, I am limiting the problem only to URLs with subdomains and with .com domain.
For example:

```
www.aBC.com      #MATCH
abc.com          #MATCH
a_bc.de8f.com    #MATCH
a.com            #MATCH
abc              #NO MATCH
abc..com         #NO MATCH
```

The closest I got with my regex is `\w+.[\w]+.com` but this does not match a simple "a.com". I am using "\w" instead of "." because otherwise I don't know how to avoid two or more dots in sequence.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
(?:\w+\.)*\w+\.com
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/JbmCmz/2/).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  com                      'com'
```

Comment: Ah, I understand your solution. The group is to garantee the inclusion of 'www.' if it is present, as the second level domain will be included in the rest of the regex. When there is no 'www,.' the group will still catch it because of the asterisk.
Thank you very much.